# Property chain reasoning over rdf:type

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, pellet

I am trying to get Pellet to propagate properties from classes down to the individuals belonging to those classes. For example, if I have Class A with Property X, and Individual B with rdf:type=Class A, I want Individual B to have Property X after running the reasoner. I'm using the technique of property chain inclusion referenced on the [OWL 2 New Features](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F8:_Property_Chain_Inclusion) page. This technique works perfectly if I use my own custom properties in the property chain, but it doesn't work if I try to use rdf:type itself. Here are some relevant snips of my RDF/XML.

Ontological Class (generated by Jena; note the "spread" property, as that is what I'm trying to propagate to the individuals of class Person):

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://family/person">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="http://family/person"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
    <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://family/person"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Nothing"/>
    <j.1:spread rdf:resource="http://spread/specificSpread"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

"Spread" property itself (written manually by me, not generated with Jena since Jena's API doesn't support object property chains):

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://spread/generalSpread">
    <owl:propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type"/>
        <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://spread/generalSpread"/>
    </owl:propertyChainAxiom>
</rdf:Description>
```

Before reasoning, the person Oedipus looks like this:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://family/Oedipus">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://family/person"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

The idea is that, after reasoning, it would look something like this:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://family/Oedipus">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://family/person"/>
    <j.1:spread rdf:resource="http://spread/specificSpread"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

I have a feeling that referring to rdf:type as an rdf:resource is probably where things are getting screwy since I'm pretty sure it's not a resource. But I'm not sure how to fix it. I ran it through Pellet's command line lint program as well and it didn't seem to have a problem with it except that it created an explicit entry for rdf:type that looked like this:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&rdf;type"/>
```

Looks a little strange to me and might also be a hint that it doesn't understand my reference to rdf:type.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be going on? I'd really appreciate any help anyone could provide.

Comment: perfect question for semanticoverflow.com

Comment: Didn't exist at the time of my asking this question.

Comment: It was just a babe of only 3 months and not well known :-)  But I made the comment more for the readers that come along to this question.  And (+1) for good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very Important Edit**

It actually turns out that property propagation IS possible within the realm of OWL DL. For example, if you want to propagate the property `spread` with the value `simpleSpread` (assuming both are already defined in your RDF), you might do something like this (in RDF/XML):

```
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://family/person">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:hasValue rdf:resource="http://spread/simpleSpread"/>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://spread/hasSpread"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Restriction"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
```

**Not so important anymore**

Okay so for information completeness, I'll post the relevant answer information here. This stuff comes from talking to people on the pellet-users mailing list. The thread is archived and starts with my [initial message](http://lists.owldl.com/pipermail/pellet-users/2010-January/004326.html). Follow the thread to find out what happened in detail.

Essentially, [OWL DL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/) does not allow "reflection" upon built-in properties and datatypes. Allowing this could violate the polynomial time decidability guaranteed by OWL DL. In order to accomplish this, you have to use the [OWL RL profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_RL) of OWL Full, which treats all things in OWL equally, thus allowing the use of an inference over `rdf:type`.

The major issue with this is finding a reasoner (or combination of reasoners) that support both DL and RL, since RL is much lighter-weight and less expressive than DL (not to mention not guaranteed to be decidable in polynomial time).